# construct a function with my own type signature - avoid duplication of code

Tags: haskell, types

I have defined a data type:

```
data Citizen = J11 String String | J12 String String
```

and I want to write a function:  getName :

```
getName :: Citizen -> String
getName  (J11 firstName lastName  ) =  firstName
getName  (J12 firstName lastName  ) =  firstName
```

Is it possible to avoid duplicating the code depending on whether it is J11 or J12?  without changing the type signature?

```
getName  (XXX firstName lastName  ) =  firstName
```

..something like this...

Comment: Nope. If it makes sense for you, you might want to split the data-type into a CitizenType and Citizen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or, you can always go one level higher

```
 data Citizen a = Citizen a String String                                                                     
 firstName :: Citizen a -> String                                                                         
 firstName (Citizen _ f _) = f                                                                            

 > let j1 = Citizen J11 "John" "Doe"                                                                               
 > firstName j1                                        

 "John"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use records.

```
data Citizen =
  J11
  { firstName :: String
  , lastName  :: String
  } |
  J12
  { firstName :: String
  , lastName  :: String
  }
```

This defines for you the functions `firstName, lastName :: Citizen -> String` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple right-hand side like in your example it's not worth it. But if your function was more complex you could do something like:

```
getName citizen =
  case citizen of
    J11 first last -> f first
    J12 first last -> f first
  where 
    f = ...complex definition...
```